How to cover content with using navigation bar?
I want the navigation bar to overlap all the content in the app and I use this code to trying to do this:
SceneDelegate
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
                    
        if let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) {
            
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            
            let nav = UINavigationController()
            let mainView = StoreViewController()
            nav.viewControllers = [mainView]
            nav.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            window.rootViewController = nav
            
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
        }
    }

}

StoreViewController
class StoreViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let backgroundView = BackgroundView()
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>?
    let sections = Bundle.main.decode([Section].self, from: "section.json")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createCollectionView()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
    
    func createDataSource() {
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, item in
            switch self.sections[indexPath.section].identifier {
                
            case "featuredCell": return self.configure(FeaturedCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
                
            default: return self.configure(CarouselCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
            }
        }
        
        dataSource?.supplementaryViewProvider = { [weak self] collectionView, kind, indexPath in
            guard let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: SectionHeader.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader
            else { return nil }
            guard let firstApp = self?.dataSource?.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else { return nil }
            guard let section = self?.dataSource?.snapshot().sectionIdentifier(containingItem: firstApp)
            else { return nil }
            if section.title.isEmpty { return nil }
            sectionHeader.title.text = section.title
            sectionHeader.subtitle.text = section.subtitle
            return sectionHeader
        }
    }

    func configure<T: SelfConfiguringCell>(_ cellType: T.Type, with item: Item, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: cellType.reuseIdentifier,
            for: indexPath) as? T else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue \(cellType)")
        }
        cell.configure(with: item)
        return cell
    }
    
    func reloadData() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        snapshot.appendSections(sections)
        for section in sections { snapshot.appendItems(section.item, toSection: section) }
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }
    
    func createCollectionView() {
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createCompositionalLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundView = backgroundView
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.register(SectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: SectionHeader.reuseIdentifier)
        
        collectionView.register(CarouselCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier)
        
        createDataSource()
        reloadData()
    }

    func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            let section = self.sections[sectionIndex]
            switch section.identifier {
                
            case "featuredCell": return self.featuredSection(using: section)
                
            default: return self.carouselSection(using: section)
            }
        }
        
        return layout
    }
    
    func sectionHeader() -> NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem {
        
        let layoutSectionHeaderSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.93), heightDimension: .estimated(80))
        let layoutSectionHeader = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: layoutSectionHeaderSize, elementKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .top)
        return layoutSectionHeader
    }
    
    func carouselSection(using section: Section) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        var layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(1), heightDimension: .absolute(1))
        var layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
        
        switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
        case .phone:
            
            let a:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/8
            let b:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
            
            layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(b - (a) ), heightDimension: .absolute(b))
            layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
            layoutGroup.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: a, leading: a/2, bottom: a, trailing: a/2)
            
        case .pad:
            
            let a:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height*0.25
            let h:CGFloat = a * 1.8
            let b:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
            
            layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(b - (h)), heightDimension: .absolute(b - (a)))
            layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
            layoutGroup.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: a, leading: a/10, bottom: 0, trailing: a/10)
            
        default:
            
            print(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        }

        let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
        layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
        
        layoutSection.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (items, offset, environment) in
            
            items.forEach { item in
                let distanceFromCenter = abs((item.frame.midX - offset.x) - environment.container.contentSize.width / 2.0)
                let minScale: CGFloat = 0.7
                let maxScale: CGFloat = 1.1
                let scale = max(maxScale - (distanceFromCenter / environment.container.contentSize.width), minScale)
                item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
            }
            
            // no apparent built-in property of "scrollable content size"
            // so let's jump through some hoops to calculate it
            // we could probably make these class properties, and only update them
            // on frame change, but that's for another time...
                        
            let n: Int = self.dataSource!.snapshot().numberOfItems

            let cvw: CGFloat = self.collectionView.frame.width
            let cw: CGFloat = environment.container.contentSize.width

            let groupWidth: CGFloat = layoutGroupSize.widthDimension.dimension
                        
            // because layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior  is set to .groupPagingCentered
            // the actual scrollable width is center of item 0 to center of last item
            let scrollableWidth: CGFloat = groupWidth * CGFloat(n - 1)

            // get the group midX
            let groupMidX = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: environment.container.contentSize).midX
                        
            // calculate x-offset for first centered group
            let baseOffsetX: CGFloat = (groupMidX - (groupWidth * 0.5)) - ((cvw - cw) * 0.5)
                        
            // percent we are currently scrolled, of total scrollable width
            let pctScrolled: CGFloat = (offset.x + baseOffsetX) / scrollableWidth

            // tell the background view to update its image view x-offset
            self.backgroundView.xPercent = pctScrolled
        }
        
        return layoutSection
    }

without navigation bar:

using navigation bar:

In this case, the navigation bar covers the background and the collection view, but the collection view cells are moved down. How to fix it?

Set the collection view's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to .never.
